# install csv package in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with installing csv package in pycharm (running under python 3.5.2)

When I try to install it I get an error saying

Executed command:
`pip install --user csv`

Error occurred:
Non-zero exit code (1)

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for csv

I updated the pip package to version 9.0.1 but still nothing.

When I run the following code:

```
import csv
f = open('fl.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
f.close()
```

I get this error:

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'

I thought it was because I could not install the "csv package"

also I tried running:

```
import csv
print(dir(csv))
```

and the print result is:

['**doc**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**']

A lot of methods including csv.reader are missing

This is pretty much all the useful information up until comment #29

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130239/discussion-on-question-by-criticalth-install-csv-package-in-pycharm).

Answer (score 27):

You can't `pip install csv` because the csv module is included in the Python installation.

You can directly use :

```
import csv
```

in your program

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

for python 3, you should run this command:

```
pip install python-csv
```

Answer (score 4):

1. 'csv' is an in-built package. So you dont have to install it again in Pycharm.
2. When you try to import csv, make sure that you dont have **any file**(*created by you*) named as 'csv.py' in your project folder(or Python Path Variable folders) because of this you are not actually importing 'csv' package.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have another file in your directory called `csv.py`. And in this file you do not have a `reader` function.

Change its name to `my_csv.py`

Comment: I have only two things in my directory. script called 1.import.py and and file called fl.csv

Answer (score 0):

You should go to Terminal in PyCharm and type:

```
pip3 install python-csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Package `python-csv` was last released in August 2020 and has had no releases since then.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34728054)